# Can I check the iteration variable to know if a foreach loop ran until the end Java?

Tags: java, foreach

In Java, I want to go through a list of elements and insert a new one at the right place. I was thinking of doing it in this way:

```
for( Tab tab : tabList )
  if( newTab.getPriority() < tab.getPriority() ) {
    newTab.insertBefore(tab);
    break;
  }
if( tab == null )
  newTab.insertBefore(endMarker);
```

Unfortunately, `tab` is not accessible outside the for loop. Is there any simple way to do what I want or do I have to use a boolean?

Comment: Thanks to the two quick answers... I just figured that out and edited my question, but you were too quick. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better practice to use a `tab` variable outside the scope of the `for` loop

```
Tab selected_tab = null;

for ( Tab tab: tabList ) {
    if (tab_I_want(tab)) {
       selected_tab = tab;
       break;
    }
}

// selected_tab is either null or the tab you want
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't access a `foreach` iterator variable outside of the loop since it goes out of scope. As you wrote it, the above code doesn't compile.

There's a variety of techniques that you can use, such as using the `boolean` that you mentioned. You can also use a "[sentinel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node)", a dummy tab that you put at the end of `tabList` that has a maximum priority that is reserved for this purpose (i.e. no "real" tab can have this priority). This guarantees that the `if` condition inside the loop will be true when you reach the sentinel tab.

Finally, you can also implement your `Tab` to be `Comparable`, or define a separate `Comparator` for it, and make `tabList` an ordered collection. This way, you don't even need a sentinel, or even a `foreach` loop; you can just add the `newTab` to the sorted collection and have it figure out where to insert it. If `tabList` is a `TreeSet`, for example, the insertion will be `O(log n)`. The other techniques mentioned so far is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't compile, because of the scope of the `tab` variable. You can do the following

```
Tab lastTab = null;
for (Tab tab : tabList) {
    if (..) {
       ..
       lastTab = tab;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way to convert that into working code is:

```
insertBlock: {
    int newPriority = newTab.getPriority();
    for (Tab tab : tabs) {
        if (newPriority < tab.getPriority()) {
            newTab.insertBefore(tab);
            break insertBlock;
        }
    }
    newTab.insertBefore(endMarker);
}
```

Although it appears that not many people are familiar with the feature. As it happens, it was this feature that allows `goto` to be removed from the language.

Answer (score 0):

`tab` is scoped to the body of the `for` loop, if I remember my Java correctly (and if it works the way one would "expect", i.e. how `for` scoping works in C99 and C++), so this probably doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

`tab` is not available outside for loop. You can so many things. Using a `boolean` is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a foreach-style loop, I don't think you could know this.  However, you could use an Iterator outside of the loop:

```
Iterator iter = tabList.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  Tab newTab = iter.next();
  if( newTab.getPriority() < tab.getPriority() ) {
    newTab.insertBefore(tab);
    break;
  }
}

if (iter.hasNext()) {
  // You've still got elements left!
}
```

Comment: `iter` is not being advanced inside the loop. This code doesn't work.

Comment: Forgot to add the iter.next().  That's what you get when you don't write unit tests for your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the above. I don't believe you can modify the tabList while it is being iterated either.

One alternate way of doing this is to find the position in the list you want to add into, and do the add operation then.

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < tabList.length; i++)
{
    if( newTab.getPriority() < tabList[i].getPriority() )
        break;
}

// this will shift the current item at that index value into the next one, and insert newtab into the specified index
tabList.add(i, newTab);
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of breaking you *could* raise an exception and catch it outside the loop. I forget the syntax in Java but Python would be something like this:

```
broken = False

try:
    for i in list:
        if i.condition == True:
            raise Exception
except Exception:
    # you know something has broken the flow
    broken = True
```

Although what if the last item broke? Technically speaking every item was inspected.

Comment: @Oli - that would be a bad idea.  Creating, throwing and catching an exception is very expensive compared with setting a flag and doing a `break`.

Comment: The cost is generating the Exception instance, which while a lot larger than an if, or an iterator check, isn't huge and won't bankrupt the economy again unless you run through this code 100 times a second. It's not the best solution but it's an "out-the-box" idea for the OP if their actual flow fits it better.

Comment: I agree with Stephen, but mostly because using exceptions to drive the flow of a piece of code usually decreases its readability. I would find a break a bit less easier to read, but I guess that's a subjective issue.